# React to Button.IsPressed WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'd like to have a TextBlock changed when the button is pressed, and then return to the previous state when the button is released.

It appears that RepeatButton is not a solution here, as it only reacts to itself being held and not released - and I need to know when it is released so that I can run a proper method to return TextBlock to its original state. Being desperate I also tried to loop `while(button.IsPressed)` (yeah, I know, awful idea :() but to no avail - the code would hang (as if IsPressed did not change to false after the button had been released).

Is there any way to achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best solution, if it works for your scenario, is to use triggers and setters, either applied through a style or a template.

Comment: It appeared to me as too complex for such, as I thought, common problem. I'll see what can be done here. Thanks

Comment: `PreviewMouseDown`, `PreviewMouseUp` ... use those events to start/stop the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the cleanest way, but I decided to create multiple handlers to my button: `Click`, `PointerPressed`, `PointerCancelled`, `PointerCaptureLost`, `PointerReleased`. First two are for handling the button being pressed, while the last three are for handling the release. I used all three due to recommendation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerreleased

This is because `PointerReleased` may sometimes be substituded by other events being fired at button release.

Answer (score 0):

PreviewMouseDown and PreviewMouseUp seem to work fine, if you want both left and right click to have your desired effect:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string TextBlockPreviousState = "";
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonStatusTextBlock.Text = "foo";
    }

    private void StoreAndUpdate()
    {
        TextBlockPreviousState = ButtonStatusTextBlock.Text;
        ButtonStatusTextBlock.Text = "Button Down";
    }

    private void Restore()
    {
        ButtonStatusTextBlock.Text = TextBlockPreviousState;
    }

    private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        StoreAndUpdate();
    }

    private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Restore();
    }
}
```